# Sums of the elements in list

Tags: prolog

I have to say that there is a similar quetion [Sum of elements in list in Prolog needs little explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129409/sum-of-elements-in-list-in-prolog-needs-little-explanation), but still makes me confused.

Here is the following solution which needs some explanation.

```
 sum([H],H).
 sum([H|T],R):-sum(T,P),R is H + P.
```

Lets say we do sum([1,2,3],R).

```
 sum([1,2,3],R)
    sum([2,3],<unknown-1>)
      sum([3],<unknown-2>)
```

so where it will fulfill the fact sum([H],H) ?
I do write the variable in sum([H],H), the only output for this case is 3,
which means that in the unknown-2 here is 3, why?

Just a beginner in prolog and any answers will be great appreciate.

Comment: sum([3],<unknown-2>) clause will try to see if matches one or more clauses that you have defined.  In this case sum([3],<unknown-2>) matches with your first clause and gives unknown-2=3. It also matches the second clause because [3] = [ 3 | [ ] ] but then it calls sum([ ],P) which fails. So unknown gets the value 3 from first clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: **unification**.

When, within the scope of a predicate clause, a variable name occurs more than once, all occurrences will be **unified** with each other. The predicate for unification is `=/2`, and is declared as operator, so `=(A, A)` and `A = A` mean the same. More importantly, this:

```
=(Term, Term).
```

is the *definition* of `=/2` (see [the documentation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%29/2)!)

In your example, you have a clause that says:

```
sum([H], H).
```

This means:

> When the first argument of `sum/2` is a list with exactly one element, the second argument of `sum/2` is that element.

Because term unification is such a fundamental operation in Prolog, usually, it is not spelled out explicitly, as for example:

> When the first argument of `sum/2` is a list with exactly one element, that element and the second argument of `sum/2` are unified with each other.

At least in the SWI-Prolog documentation, if unification is involved, it is usually described with "X is Y" instead of "X and Y are unified". See, for example, [the documentation of `min_member/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=min_member/2):

> **min_member**(`Min`, `List`).
>
> True when `Min` is the smallest member in the standard order of terms. Fails if `List` is empty.

It doesn't explicitly tell you that unification is used, and from that, the following behavior follows:

```
?- min_member(3, [1,2,X]).
X = 3.
```

I once [asked a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27374797/1812457) because I found it too confusing.

By the way, with your current definition of `sum/2`, you can also get surprises because of the way that unification works. Look:

```
?- sum([1.5, 2.5], Sum).
Sum = 4.0 ; % unnecessary choice point but at least correct
false.

?- sum([1.5, 2.5], 4).
false. % Oops!
```

The [SWI-Prolog library implementation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#sum_list/2) suffers from the same problem:

```
?- sum_list([1.5, 2.5], Sum).
Sum = 4.0. % no choice point, at least

?- sum_list([1.5, 2.5], 4).
false. % Oops!
```

The work-around is to leave the second argument a free variable at first, and then use `=:=/2`, which does *arithmetic comparison of numbers*:

```
?- sum_list([1.5, 2.5], Sum), Sum =:= 4.
Sum = 4.0.
```

You can do this with your definition of `sum/2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
sumList([],0).
sumList([X|Tail],Sum):-
    sumList(Tail,Sum1),
    Sum is Sum1+X.
```